# searching for clear int values with addAjaxFilterBox in ajaxCrud

Tags: php, ajax, crud

I'm trying to search for clear int values with the addAjaxFilterBox function in ajaxCrud class.

Writing into addAjaxFilterBox field "Numbers" the number 63, the results will show every result that contains the number.

However, I want it to show me only the exact record as it would be written as a string.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

$tblDemo->setExactSearchField('fldFieldName');